# Iterate through dict key with a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict like this:

```
my_dict={val1:True, val2:False, val3:False, val4:True}
```

How do I iterate through this dict's keys that have value `False`?

Comment: You can’t, you’ll have to iterate through all of them and check whether the value is false.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `List comprehension` :

```
[key for key,val in my_dict.items() if val==False]
```

This will return a `list` containing the `keys` that have `value` as `False` . Now, it is a simple matter of going through the `list`.

#driver values :

```
IN : my_dict = {'a': True,'b': False, 'c': True, 'd': False}
OUT : ['b','d']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> my_dict={'val1':True,'val2':False,'val3':False,'val4':True}
>>> [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if not v]
['val2', 'val3']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution of your problem :

```
for i,j in my_dict.items():
    if j is False:
        print(i)
```

> Additional information :
>
> In python we can use `if something:` for checking truthy and falsy :

so :

```
for i,j in my_dict.items():

    if not j:
        print(i)
```

You can use generator expression :

```
print(list((key for key,value in my_dict.items() if not value)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter them first, this is a working example:

```
for key in (k for k, v in my_dict.items() if not v):
    print(key)
```

This works by going through all the (key, value) pairs, and iterating over the `key`s that have a negative `value`

Comment: OP is looking for `False`, not `True`.

Comment: I just fixed it :)